# Set automatic profile picture after upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In my social network site i have options like on fb user can change profile picture. When user click on profile image new modal window is opened where user can choose existing image to set on profile or to upload new. Uploading new photo is done via `form inptu[file]` and i send request with ajax. Am using Codeigniter fw for this app. Images are successfull uploaded on dir and stored in database. My problem is bcs i dont have idea how to automaticly set that new uploaded photo as profile photo. In `users` table i have `cell` named `porfile_picture` where i store `id` of picture witch user pick. Setting new picture on profile i do with `UPDATE` sql query, change existing picture id with new.

**Model for uploading new picture:**

```
public function create($data = array())
{
    $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);

}
```

**In controller i have standard method from ci doc how to upload image**

```
public function uploadProfilePicture()
{ 
     // image lib settings and validations 

     $photo_data = array(
            'owner_id' => $this->_accountID,
            'album_id' => 5, // profilne slike album
            'photo_name' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'],
            'photo_ext' => $data['upload_data']['file_ext'],
            'photo_size' => $data['upload_data']['file_size'],
            'photo_type' => $data['upload_data']['image_type'],
            'date_uploaded' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'date_midified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'photo_guid' => $guid
        );

        //debug_view($data);
        $this->photo->create($photo_data);
}

public function setProfilePicture($picture_id = 0)
{
        $this->account->edit($this->_accountID, array(
            'profile_picture' => $picture_id,
        ));

        redirect('profile');
}
```

**Uploading is done via ajax:**

```
// Upload picture
$("#upload_profile_image").on('submit', function(e) {
     var picture = $(".profile_picture").val();

    $(".loader-wrapper").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        url: baseurl + '/photo/uploadProfilePicture',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $(".loader-wrapper").hide();
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

This uploading work perfect now only what i need to know how to set that uploaded image as prifile. I need to send one more query in database to update `profile_picture`.

Do you have a suggestion

Comment: You should return new image path to your AJAX response and after `$(".loader-wrapper").hide();` you could change image src for the new one.

Comment: show your view file html